# Probability of two friends being in the same group

Tags: probability

If 10 people are divided into 2 equal groups(each group has 5 people) whats the probability that two friends A and B are in the same group?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: A is definitely in A's group.  How many others are in A's group?

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

You can count all the possible groups:

$$\binom{10}{5} = 252 \textrm{ groups}$$

Pick 3 people to be in a group with A and B:
$$\binom{8}{3} = 56 \textrm{ groups with A and B together}$$

Alternatively, we might select a 5-person group with neither A nor B:
$$\binom{8}{5} = 56 \textrm{ groups with A and B together}$$

This gives us a total of $112$ arrangements with A and B together:

$$\frac{112}{252} = \frac{4}{9}$$

**Method 2**

Fix A in any group. There are 4 spots left in that group, and 5 in the other group, so there must be a $\frac{4}{9}$ chance of B being placed in the group with A

Comment: Why is it that we must count $8 \choose 3$ essentially twice? Does $8 \choose 3$ not account for both selecting 3 people to be in a group with A and B and for selecting a 5-person group with neither A nor B?

Comment: @Cat  The first method applies to groups that are labeled.  There are $\binom{10}{5}$ labeled groups.  If A and B are both in the blue group, then there are $\binom{8}{3}$ ways of selecting the other members of the blue group.  If they are both in the red group, then there are $\binom{8}{5}$ ways of picking the members of the blue group.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig is correct - remember that this counts a splitting of the group of $10$ into $2$ smaller groups. Taking $\binom {10}{5}$ counts the number of ways to pick the first group. A and B might be together because they were both chosen for the first group, or because neither was in the first group and they were forced into the second.