# Probability of ending up in the same group

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

There's 6 groups, I'm in the first, and my friend is in another. The teacher then decides to merge all groups in pairs of 2. So there's gonna be 3 groups. What is the probability that me and my friend ends up in the same new group?

My mind is very split as I read this: [Probability of two friends being in the same group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194375/probability-of-two-friends-being-in-the-same-group?fbclid=IwAR0Cd60vqozgrd5XIOon0PSqQz_40uRwtB_uXnron28otwM918XMeF5l9Mg)

**One solution**: I thought of is that we have: 6 over 3 as the total combinations: which is 20.
Then i can count all the times me and my friend end up in the same group, which should be: 4 over 0, as no other person can join our group.
As there's 3 groups, i multiply by 3. So 3/20 total chance of ending up in the same group.

**The other solution**: I thought that since there's 5 other groups, apart from my, there's 1/5 chance that he ends up in the same group.

**So im not sure if either is Correct, or how to better calculate it, any help is appreciated.**

If there's any help. It started as 60 students, split into 6 groups of 10.
Where i calculated it should be 9/59 chance that we end up in the same group:

Comment: Your second argument is correct. I don't understand your first one.

Answer (score 1):

Your second argument is correct

Perhaps your first argument should be something like this: you could say there are $\frac1{3!}{6 \choose 2}{4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}= 15$ ways of pairing the groups. Of these, there are $\frac1{2!}{4 \choose 2}{2 \choose 2}=3$ with  your group and your friend's group together, giving a probability of $\frac3{15}=\frac15$

So the error in your first argument is the number $20$.  To convince you that $15$ is correct, here is the full list:

```
AB,CD,EF    AB,CE,DF    AB,CF,DE    
AC,BD,EF    AC,BE,DF    AC,BF,DE    
AD,BC,EF    AD,BE,CF    AD,BF,CE    
AE,BC,DF    AE,BD,CF    AE,BF,CD    
AF,BC,DE    AF,BD,CE    AF,BE,CD
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i had trouble writing out the full list, and realizing the fact that i should divide by 3!... , This sums it up really nice.