# Probability to find two numbers in the same group

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The integers from 1 to 100 are randomly separated into two groups of 50 integers each. What is the probability that 37 and 89 are in the same group?

My reasoning in this exercise is to first put one number in one of the possible 100 positions and then place the second one : For the first one there is no restrictions and for the second one there are 49/99 possible position.Besides the positions of the other numbers are not important so i think that the answer is 49/99 , am i right?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Find out for smaller numbers like $2,4$ instead of $100$ in order to gain some intuition.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes i fell very exposed when i solve probability problems because it's difficult to check the correctness of your reasoning :$

Comment: Thank you to have suggested me to give a try , i have to acknowledge that it's way better like this

Comment: These are nice things to hear. Good luck with your study of probabiity,

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194375/probability-of-two-friends-being-in-the-same-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning and your answer of $\frac{49}{99}$ are correct

Another less efficient approach might be to say there are ${100 \choose 50}$ equally likely different possibilities of choosing the first part, and of these ${2 \choose 2}{98 \choose 48}+{2 \choose 0}{98 \choose 50}$ have your two specific values together in either the first or the second part.  Divide the latter by the former and simplify to get the same result